# Extract information (subset) from a main files using a list of identifiers saved in another file

Tags: linux, sed, grep, extract

I have one file containing a list of name (refer as file 1):

```
Apple 
Bat
Cat
```

I have another file (refer as file 2) containing a list of name and details refer:

```
Apple bla blaa
aaaaaaaaaggggggggggttttttsssssssvvvvvvv
ssssssssiiuuuuuuuuuueeeeeeeeeeennnnnnnn
sdasasssssssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwww
Aeroplane  dsafgeq dasfqw dafsad
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuus
fcsadssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
ddddddddddddddddwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
sdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwwwwwwwww
Bat    sdasdas  dsadw   dasd
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssswww
ssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwf
aaaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwddddddd
sadddddddddddddddddd
Cat   dsafw    fasdsa   dawwdwaw
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwssss
```

I need to extract info out of file 2 using the list of names in file 1.
Output file should be something like below:

```
Apple bla blaa
aaaaaaaaaggggggggggttttttsssssssvvvvvvv
ssssssssiiuuuuuuuuuueeeeeeeeeeennnnnnnn
sdasasssssssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwww
Bat    sdasdas  dsadw   dasd
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssswww
ssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwf
aaaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwddddddd
sadddddddddddddddddd
Cat   dsafw    fasdsa   dawwdwaw
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwssss
```

Is there any commands for doing this using Linux (Ubuntu)? I am a new Linux user.

Comment: Could you shorten your samples? Try to make your question better readable and understandable.

Comment: Use the formatting tool to better format your code and advise new lines correctly...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also use the `{}` button to format example instead of quote... it is not clear whether empty lines are part of input.. see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ...

Comment: How do you propose to find the end of the relevant data?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that each section has to be separated by an empty line, this solution with awk works ok:

```
while read -r pat;do
  pat="^\\\<${pat}\\\>"
  awk -vpattern=$pat '$0 ~ pattern{p=1}$0 ~ /^$/{p=0}p==1' file2
done <file1
```

This solution to work , requires the file to like this:

```
Apple bla blaa
1 aaaaaaaaaggggggggggttttttsssssssvvvvvvv
2 ssssssssiiuuuuuuuuuueeeeeeeeeeennnnnnnn
3 sdasasssssssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwww

Aeroplane  dsafgeq dasfqw dafsad
4 vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuus
5 fcsadssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
6 ddddddddddddddddwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
7 sdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwwwwwwwww

Bat    sdasdas  dsadw   dasd
8 sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssswww
9 ssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwf
10 aaaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwddddddd
11 sadddddddddddddddddd

Cat   dsafw    fasdsa   dawwdwaw
12 sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
13 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwssss
```

PS: Numbering has been applied by me in order to be able to "check" that awk will return the correct results per section. Numbering is not required in your real file.

If there are not empty lines separating each section then it is much harder to achieve the correct result.

Comment: That would be very inefficient and fragile courtesy of the shell loop (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) and it'd match the target string anywhere on the line instead of just on the first field plus it's match on any line not just targeted ones and even if that was fixed, it'd produce false matches if file1 contained `Grape` and file2 had a line starting with `Grapefruit`, and so on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried and it produce false matches as describes by @EdMorton.

Comment: @SuboonChua Try updated code in my answer  with gnu awk.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/^&/bb#' file1 |
sed -e ':a' -f - -e 'd;:b;n;/^[A-Z]/!bb;ba' file2
```

Generate a string of sed commands from the first file and pipe them into another sed script which is run against the second file.

The first file creates a regexp for each line which when matched jumps to a piece of common code. If none of the regexps are matched the lines are deleted. If a regexp is matched then further lines are printed until a new delimiter is found at which point the code then jumps to the start and the process is repeated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But it return nothing. 'sed 's#.*#/^&/bb#' file1' is working but when I entered 'sed -e ':a' -f - -e 'd;:b;n;/^[A-Z]/!bb;ba' file2', it seem to be stucked and return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} NF>1{f=($1 in a)} f' file1 file2
Apple bla blaa
aaaaaaaaaggggggggggttttttsssssssvvvvvvv
ssssssssiiuuuuuuuuuueeeeeeeeeeennnnnnnn
sdasasssssssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwww
Bat    sdasdas  dsadw   dasd
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssswww
ssssssssssssssssswwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwf
aaaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwddddddd
sadddddddddddddddddd
Cat   dsafw    fasdsa   dawwdwaw
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwssss
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. 

I have entered  'awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} NF>1{f=($1 in a)} f' file1 file2' but it return nothing. 

I tried  'awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} NF>1{f=($1 in a)} f' file1 file2 >output' and it generated 0 byte file.

Comment: Then you either copy/pasted wrong or your input isn't as shown in your question. As you can see I tested the solution against your posted sample input and it produced your posted expected output so the script DOES do what you asked for.